# Cmder doesn't log anymore

Tags: bash, logging, windows-subsystem-for-linux, cmder

Cmder settings: Win + Alt + P > startup > tasks.

Since the shift from task WSL::bash (which didn't work anymore due an update) to bash::bash log files are created in `%ConEmuDir%\Logs\`, but it creates only empty files.
The problem seems to be in the settings below, because when I startup with WSL::bash it does create a log message which includes a WSL bridge error.

WSL::bash settings (old):

```
set "PATH=%ConEmuBaseDirShort%\wsl;%PATH%" & %ConEmuBaseDirShort%\conemu-cyg-64.exe --wsl -cur_console:pm:/mnt
```

bash::bash settings (current):

```
set PATH="%ConEmuBaseDirShort%\wsl";%PATH% & wsl -d debian
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just a heads-up that your question is very difficult to read currently.  I recommend adding some [code-blocks](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-format-code-in-markdown/) to make it easier to understand the commands and output you are seeing.

Comment: Good thinking, done. Issue still exists